# Как в ActiveAdmin сделать что либо после/во время update`а?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу сделать следующее: при обновлении записи одной модели, сделать что нибудь, хоть `puts "Hello world!"` выполнить. 
Не понимаю как добавить какое либо действие в стандартные action`ы activeadmin для одной модели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, повесить на событие сохранения callback, например, `after_commit` или `after_save`

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_save do |record|
    Rails.logger.info 'Hello world!'
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте это.

```
controller do
  def update
     puts "Hello world!"
  end
end
```